# How can I find an Element with which has several attributes at different positions with a generic XPATH?

Tags: xml, xpath

My XML structure looks like:

```
<a id="1">
    <b>
        <c>
            <d class="scope now"/>
        </c>
    </b>
</a>
```

I try to find the Element d which has to have the attribute id = 1 and the class whitch contains now with the xpath below:

```
//*[@id="1"]/b/c/d[contains(@class, 'now')]
```

Is there a way how I can leave out the element's b and c in the xpath to have a more generic xpath? 
There are a lot of changes between these elements and I won't alter every time the xpath.

Comment: you can use like this //*[@id="1"]//*[contains(@class, 'now')]

Comment: you don't need to alter anything if you use the above one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can omit elements and use `//` to tell XPath [to search for any child or deeper descendant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath#Abbreviated_syntax):

```
//*[@id="1"]//d[contains(@class, 'now')]
```